# Solution of equation help

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given that $\small x^2+12\sqrt x=5$, calculate $\small x+2\sqrt x$.

Comment: What have your tried? What difficulty are you having?

Comment: I want to find the value of  x+2√x

Comment: Yes I can read the question. But what effort have you made to find a solution? You have used the tag "solution verification." What solution did you get and why do you think it might not be correct?

Comment: I can't show the terms of x+2√x

Comment: Have you solved any similar problems?

Comment: Yes, But easier than that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try factorising $x^2+12\sqrt{x}-5$ as :

$$(x+A\sqrt{x}+B)(x+C\sqrt{x}+D)=x^2+(A+C)x\sqrt{x}+(B+D+AC)x$$ $$+(AD+BC)\sqrt{x}+BD$$

Comparing coefficients we require $A+C=0, B+D+AC=0, AD+BC=12, BD=-5$.

If $B=-1, D=+5$ then $5A-C=12$ while $A+C=0$ so $A=+2, C=-2$.
*Check :* $B+D+AC=-1+5-4=0$.

If $B=+1, D=-5$ then $-5A+C=12$ while $A+C=0$ so $C=+2, A+-2$.
*Check :* $B+D+AC=+1-5-4 \ne 0$.

The only such factorisation is

$$x^2+12\sqrt{x}-5=(x+2\sqrt{x}-1)(x-2\sqrt{x}+5)=0$$

The second factor has the solutions $$\sqrt{x}=1\pm 2i$$ therefore $$x=1-2\mp 4i=-1\mp 4i$$ $$x+2\sqrt{x}=-1\mp 4i+2\pm 4i=+1$$

For the 1st factor also $$x+2\sqrt{x}=+1$$

---

A slightly different method :

Let $u=x+2\sqrt{x}$ and $v=x-2\sqrt{x}$. Then $$u+v=2x, u-v=4\sqrt{x}, uv=x^2-4x$$  Substitute into the original equation : $$x^2+12\sqrt{x}-5=uv+2(u+v)+3(u-v)-5=uv+5u-v-5=(u-1)(v+5)=0$$ Hence $$u=x+2\sqrt{x}=1$$

Comment: Thank you very much I am very happy for your help